# Sum each block of row in column B until value of column A is equal in row

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with an Excel sheet, with the name of department in column A, name of person in respective department in column B & in column C there is salary amount paid to the employee.

What I need to do is perform a task to sum the salary department-wise & answer should appear in column D.

The answer will show me what amount is being paid to each department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `SUMIF` function:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"Specific Department",C:C)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. But here I have to write department name. OR need to make a list of department. can it be performed by VBA that will automaticlly find the change in column A & sum column B.

Comment: You could have: `=SUMIF(A:A,A1,C:C)` in D1 which would give the `Sum` for the department on `Row 1` then copy it down

Answer (score 0):

List your departments in column **E** and then in **F1** enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A=E1)*(C:C))
```

and copy down:

[image]